# Sharepoint XSL dropdown populated form a list

Tags: xslt, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to use a CEWP to display a list of items as a drop down list.

Specifically im trying to set the value to the url and then the title as the item shown in the drop down. 
This is what I have so far

```
    <xsl:template name="HubJumpTo" match="Row[@Style='HubJumpTo']" mode="itemstyle">
<select id="mySelect"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="/item"> 
    <option>
    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>          
    </option> 
    </xsl:for-each> 

</select> 
</xsl:template>
```

But the CEWP isn't showing any fields for me to specifiy which coloumn in the list should popul;ate value and name. Any suggestions why this might be?

The drop down isn't populating with anything and I assume this is because of this isse.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a typo in your question (in which case, this answer will self-destruct...), but the problem may lie in this line

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/item">
```

Because the xpath expression starts with a forward slash `/`, then this represents the document node, and so the expression is looking for the root element of the name **item**. There is only one root element in the document, and I guessing it is not called item!

You probably need to use a relative expression here, assuming **item** is a child element of the currently matched **Row** element.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="item">
```

Comment: Nope - this doesnt resovle the issue.

Comment: All i want is a drop down box that when yo uselect an option and hit go it takes u to that page. I want the xsl to populate the contents of one drop down box from info from a list.

Comment: It's a bit hard to offer more help without actually seeing your input XML.

Comment: Input XML? I gave it above didnt I? confused :S

Comment: There is no sign of the input XML in your question. You have shown the XSLT, but not the input XML that it being transformed by the XSLT.

Comment: Its a shrepoint list which has 3 coloumns - URL TITLE and Team Title

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems bit ambiguous, you say CEWP i.e. "Content editor Webpart" how come you can use CEWP with XSLT for rendering list? it should be like, you need to add list view webpart and pass your custom xslt path to it.
also i see match="Row[@Style='HubJumpTo']" so do you have a column named 'Style'? and are there any rows with value "HubJumpTo"

Answer (score 0):

DID this using SP services in the end.